# jquery dialog zoom show effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I don't know if this has been asked and answered elsewhere, but I could not find what I'm looking for. I want to use jQuery.dialog() and have it "zoomed" to open. Is that possible?

This is basically what I want, but I need to know how to do that with a dialog: http://jsfiddle.net/HDmff/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like that?
http://jsfiddle.net/A4k2g/1/

Hiding needs some tweeks, I know that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i figured it out. I needed to manipulate the parents, not the return of the dialog() function.

Here's the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WTbgt/

And here's the forum thread that helped me solve it: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/animate-dialog-increase-size